# Event adding problem in Android

Tags: android

In my app I have to add an event. The event has a start date, end date, start time, end time and description. **I do not know now how to add** start date and end date to event.

I use the following code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
            intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
            startActivity(intent);
```

And when I run this code it asks me to add or cancel in the calendar. But my need is, that it should be added without user interaction. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem by using the Google Calendar. the following website is very use full.

http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm

http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/08/09/add-events-on-google-calendar-on-android-froyo/